# Transform Panda dataframe to this shape

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
In [98]: myDict
Out[98]:
{'2015-08-07': [{'redoPerSec': 300}, {'Transactions': 100}, {'IOPS': 400}],
 '2015-08-06': [{'redoPerSec': 300}, {'Transactions': 100}, {'IOPS': 400}]}

In [99]: df = pandas.DataFrame(myDict)

In [100]: df
Out[100]:
              2015-08-06             2015-08-07
0    {'redoPerSec': 300}    {'redoPerSec': 300}
1  {'Transactions': 100}  {'Transactions': 100}
2          {'IOPS': 400}          {'IOPS': 400}
```

I would want to convert this to something below

```
Date            redoPerSec          Transactions    IOPS
2015-08-06          300                 100         400
2015-08-07          300                 100         400
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? if so please include the python code so someone can with your specific issue.

Comment: I am new to pandas and still getting my head around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['2015-08-06'] = [{'redoPerSec': 300}, {'Transactions': 100}, {'IOPS': 400}]
df['2015-08-07'] = [{'redoPerSec': 300}, {'Transactions': 100}, {'IOPS': 400}]

df = df.T

for i in range(3):
    df = df.join(df[i].apply(Series)).drop(i, 1)

df.index.name = 'Date'
print df
```

Output:

```
            redoPerSec  Transactions  IOPS
Date                                      
2015-08-06         300           100   400
2015-08-07         300           100   400
```

#### Edit

Since you create `DataFrame` from `dict`, you can directly use

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myDict, 'index')
```

instead of creating a `DataFrame` and then transpose it through `df = df.T`.

A more element solution is first transforming your `dict` such that the value is a `dict` instead of a `list` of `dict`, although the nested dict comprehension is harder to understand. After that we can directly construct `DataFrame` as expected.

```
import pandas as pd

myDict = {'2015-08-07': [{'redoPerSec': 300}, {'Transactions': 100}, {'IOPS': 400}],
 '2015-08-06': [{'redoPerSec': 300}, {'Transactions': 100}, {'IOPS': 400}]}

myDict = { k0: { k: v for d in v0 for (k, v) in d.items() } for (k0, v0) in myDict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myDict, 'index')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton i tried this for 4 hours and couldn't get that shape.I am still trying to learn your code though

Comment: Hi Can you please explain what this line of code does df.join(df[i].apply(Series)).drop(i, 1)

Comment: `df[i]` gets each column. `apply(Series)` applys `Series` function to the column, which creates `Series` from the inner `dict`. `join` append created `Series` to the end of column, and `drop` deletes the original column.

Comment: Thank you so much ,That was very kind of you Sir

Comment: No worries. I just updated a new version which only needs two lines of code.